# Как скопировать содержимое ячейки TValueListEditor?

Tags: delphi

Не понимаю как сделать копирование содержимого ячейки в буфер.

У меня два столбика

Нужно что бы выделялась ячейка при клике на нее.

Помогите, пожалуйста! Спасибо

Comment: Есть кто??

Answer (score 1):

Компонент написан на основе `TStringGrid`. Отталкивайтесь от свойств `Row` и `Col`, и примените их к свойству `Cells`, таким образом, получите текущую выбранную ячейку.

Далее объектом `Clipboard` загребаете текст в буфер.

Comment: Я так и делал, только мне нужно брать из двух столбиков. А при клике на любую ячейку в строке я вывожу в сообщение Row ид, и там показывается ID строки а не ячейки, там самым я не могу занести данные определенной ячейки. Конечно можно сделать Cells[0, id] но как я буду определять по какой ячейки я кликнул?